# Body centered cubic lattice vs Primitive cubic unit cell

Tags: crystal-structure, solid-state-chemistry, crystallography

I was reading about Bravias lattices(cubic crystal system) when got confused about an article in my book.

Please refer to [Counting body center as lattice point when basis consists of 2 atoms](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94400/counting-body-centre-as-lattice-point-when-the-basis-consists-of-2-atoms).

The answer there makes me think about these two cases:-
[image: fig1]
[image: fig2]
In figure 1, the crystal is produced by conbining the body centered lattice frame with a single atom motif.

In figure 2, the crystal lattice is produced by combining a primitive cubic lattice frame with a motif made of 2 atoms.

Both things lead to that same result so would we calk the final crystal formed a a body centered cubic lattice or a primitive cubic lattice?

P.S : The book I am using(a private institution book, tution book to be precise) has unclear definitions creating a lot of problem so pardon me if you had found me saying weird things.

Comment: This is about the difference between the conventional unit cell and the asymmetric cell. Have a look at https://www.crystallographiccourseware.com/unitcells/UnitCellMain.html for a very quick and colourful summary, and if I get time I'll try to write an answer