# Question about Elemental Sulfur

Tags: crystal-structure

I am trying to understand the structure of elemental, crystalline sulfur. I read that it is face-centered orthorhombic. My question is whether each point on the unit lattice contains a single atom of sulfur or a S6 molecule?

Thanks to anyone reading.

Comment: Also worth noting that there are many allotropes of elemental sulphur with *different* crystal structures and molecular makeups.

Comment: Please see https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94400/counting-body-centre-as-lattice-point-when-the-basis-consists-of-2-atoms/94473#94473

Comment: There is no "whether". Crystal structures simply do not work like that. Besides, elemental sulfur typically consists of S8, not S6.